# Possible DVI Splitter Issues?

Tags: display, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, projector

I am thinking about buying a DVI splitter cable online and a DVI-> HDMI adapter. Can i use these to clone my graphic cards output so one can go to my monitor, and the other to my projector?

Can anyone think of any issues with using the adapter like this? Would there be problems with signal loss or anything?

Thanks

Comment: as it turns out there was an EDID clash error that would sometimes mess up the resolutions that were allowed. Also the compture and project both would refuse to boot which is awesome [you could have them, just not at boot time]. So this sucks. Any other ideas to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said above this created an EDID Clash and both projecter computer would refuse to boot with this connected.

Ended up getting an active DVI splitter, which while expensive, did the job perfectly

Got this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000MPL5ZC/ref=oss_product

Answer (score 2):

This will work without any signal problem if the wires are not extremely long. HDCP might not work when 2 screen are connected on a splitter.

Another problem is the resolution will be the same on both output and one screen might force is EDID. This can be a problem if the resolution of this monitor is lower than the other output because the higher resolution will be unavailable while the second monitor is connected.